# broadcasting push notifications to android c2dm

Tags: android, android-c2dm, urbanairship.com

how can broadcasting the push notifications be done to all devices using my application. I have seen this feature in Urban airship, which sends broadcast message to all devices which has the application. I need to use my own program to send broadcast. Can this be done?? If yes how? I have searched on google but i could not find a satisfying answer. Any links regarding this would be helpful.

Thank you

**EDIT**

```
curl --header "Authorization: GoogleLogin auth=*my auth key here*" "https://android.apis.google.com/c2dm/send" -d registration_id=<registration id of the device> -d "data.payload=You have recieved a Push Notification" -d collapse_key=0 -k
```

I have been using this to send notification, the notification gets delivered to the registered device, i.e. emulator. I need to send notification to all the device which is using my application. How is it achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C2dm from google enables to send push messages to your application running on multiple devices.For this you have to register a gmail account with google c2dm service.also your device should have registered with google with any google account and should have market installed

```
http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/signup.html
```

follow the link.documentation is good.hope this help

```
http://blog.mediarain.com/2011/03/simple-google-android-c2dm-tutorial-push-notifications-for-android/
http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidCloudToDeviceMessaging/article.html
```

have a look at above basic tutorials too

your application structure should be somewhat like thi accepting registration ids from all devices when they get registered and looping through these ids and send messages

Comment: I already have tried the code by vogella, the server side implementation is using java and the messages are sent using curl commands. it only sends the message/notification to the device with registration id. I'll edit my post and will add the curl commandline.

Comment: registration id is what you get ehen your device first sends registration intent to c2dm servers .it is required by your server side app to send push notification.

Comment: so do i have to write my own application for server side to send broadcast?

Comment: sure you have to write your server side application.see the updated answer

Comment: thank you, can you please tell me where i can find serverside programming regarding my requirement to send broadcast notifications. links, tutorials any material would be helpful. Thanks again.

Comment: http://techtej.blogspot.com/2010/10/android-c2dm-messaging-server-push-for.html foll.ole the link for an overview on how this works and implement the service.